# One to many relationship in Entity Framework on legacy DB with inheritance

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to map an existing (legacy) database to the entity framework, however I experience the following exception:

Type 'Product' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 5, column 1.

```
public class BaseProduct
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set;}
}

public class Option
{

   public int ProductId{ get; set;}
   public int Time{ get; set;} 
   public int Value{ get; set;

   public virtual BaseProduct { get; set;}
}

public class Product : BaseProduct
{


}
```

The primary keys are (not defined in the database):

`Product.Id` and a combined key of
`Option.ProductId, Option.Time`

I want to define a one to many relationship between Product and Option (one product has multiple options).

I've created the following -code first- entity framework configurations:

```
public ProductConfiguration() 
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id); 
}
```

and

```
public OptionConfiguration() 
{
    HasKey(x => new {x.ProductId, x.Time});
    HasRequired(x => x.Product); 
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: did yout try : `HasRequired(x => x.Product).WithMany(y => y.Options).HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);` ?

Comment: You could also use EF6 Tools for VS to reverse engineer the definitions for you. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: Hey, it is working indeed. However, I moved the Option Collection to the base class, and it isn't working anymore.